# Raised Grievance and Monitoring at work

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

I raised a grievance at work about 2 weeks ago and an investigation is occurring into another employee.

The main problem is I think they have no intention of investigating this other employee but to investigate me.

Another problem is the details of this investigation has been leaked around the company and now I'm being criticized for the most trivial things.

My supervisor who has praised me for my hard work prior to this is now saying my report writing is too slow and now has said "He wants to sit with me and watch me write a report from start to finish to see why" which can take a day or two depending on the amount of data there is to graph.

I don't know if he was joking but if he wasn't then this is going to seriously cause me to have an anxiety attack as I have an anxiety disorder.

Can he do this? can I tell him no as I don't want to do anything that will embarrass me in front of other employees? can I request him to send me an email explaining why he wants to do this with approval from his manager? Does anyone have any advise?

Cheers Dave M

Comment: I've had an anxiety disorder since 2004 and I take meds for this but now I'm being treated for work related stress (mainly because of certain people trying to force me out over the space of 4 years). The doctor did recommend going on sick leave for treatment but I don't like the idea of that because I refuse to give in to bullies and that's what certain people want. So now I'm on a medication that is similar to valium but without the addiction problems valium has.

Comment: The other employee being investigated has been with the company for decades as well as the head manager who are close friends. There's no way that the head manager will allow any investigation into the other employee. From certain remarks over the 2 weeks, I believe that everything will be done to discredit me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Your « good » reads like an insult. Did you mean good that they are trying to discredit the OP or that the OP is on meds?

Comment: location/country, company size?

Comment: The company is a major global one that bought out a smaller company I started with. The company was a typical toxic workplace i.e. poor management, high turnover and a disregard for following policy. This poor management is still in place and the look on HR's face's when I showed them emails about getting pointed to the previous company's policies and not to the new ones was priceless.

Comment: My complaint has clearly rattled management and now there is a major effort to remind employees of policy in different parts of the company along with the sudden change of me being the highly competent employee prior to the complaint to now being someone no one comes to and gets criticized for the most trivial things.

Comment: @D_Middy Please do not jump to conclusions, that really does not help you. *they have no intention of investigating this other employee* and  *I refuse to give in to bullies and that's what certain people want* are both unfounded.

Answer (score 11):

That sounds like a horrible situation, but unfortunately no one on this site will be able to give you advice that will fix it.

Find a lawyer who specialises in employment law in your area and follow *their* advice instead.

Comment: I would agree with this comment.  If this is taking place in the United States, increasing monitoring may be considered retaliation in some scenarios, such as EEO.  Note that I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.  I second the recomendation of finding an employment lawyer.

Answer (score -2):

Look for another Job.

Your manager obviously is building a case against you or is intimidating you.

Their end goal is to ensure you leave the company, and they will succeed eventually.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is getting so much flak.  The relationship between the employee and their manager is showing symptoms of being abusive, and will only escalate.  Lawsuits cost money, and trust me a lawsuit most likely spanning over months and the financial strain it brings is only going to add to your anxiety.  Putting this behind you and moving on before termination is the best option for both your professional  reputation and finances.

Comment: @persona_non_grata Job searching can take months, or even years, so just telling them to job search without giving any advice on how to deal with the situation they're currently in is very short-sighted (even if I do agree OP should send some feelers out now). As for your comment, looking at their legal options is a very good first step, and it doesn't mean they have to go ahead with a lengthy and costly lawsuit. Employee's have rights, telling them to not even bother to check them is bad.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if your supervisor can legally watch you work, however personally I don't find this unusual, as sometimes the supervisor may realize that an employee needs additional training for some skill that is needed on a daily basis. This isn't exactly a form of criticism (or I don't see it as such), and it could be beneficial especially for employees on junior levels.

If you are anxious about being observed, I believe approaching your supervisor personally and discussing the situation will help clarify why this is necessary. I'm afraid I can't give you more specific advice as details around your grievance are missing. If you would explain what you complained about, others might be better able to understand your situation.

Comment: Last year I was told I would be promoted given that I met certain objectives which I did. I was told a few weeks ago that me and no other employee would be promoted only to find that another employee (also a friend of the other employee) with much less experience than me had been promoted. I demanded to know why I wasn't promoted and quoted company policy on promotions (Which I asked HR for a year ago and had to email WHQ HR in the U.S.). This is why I think I am being discredited so the other guys promotion was justified. If anyone has an opinion on this then feedback would be great.

Comment: Have you received any answer to your grievance? Has there been any attempt to address or argument the promotion of this other person? If not, and indeed you are more qualified, I suppose nobody is preparing to fire you, but it sounds like they might be hoping to get you to drop your complaint by scrutinizing your work.

Comment: Hi xyz, no answers yet, the meeting was on the 11th. I think their stalling because they know the promotion was obviously unjustified. Maybe they are trying to dig up some dirt on me or intentionally overload me with work. I know at least 1 guy who was forced out and know this for a fact.

Comment: It sounds like this is a pattern of behavior within your branch of the company, or within your team. If this is true, you should consider whether you want to invest more time into your current employer, or whether it is time to look for a healthier and fairer environment. Perhaps your company is big enough that you can switch internally?